# Start a part at the same page in the Book style

Tags: parts

I have several parts in my book and I do not want them to start on a new page. The picture of desired examplery [image]layout is attached. Please help me to solve this task.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `straight` option from `titlesec`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\part}{straight}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\centering\partname\ \thepart}{20pt}{\Huge\centering}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\begin{document}
\part{test}
\lipsum[2]
\part{another test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also modify the formatting of the parts with `titlesec` to make them closer to your image.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\part}{straight}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {}{\centering\partname\ \thepart}{0pt}{\large\centering}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{10pt}{10pt}
\begin{document}
\part{test}
\lipsum[2]
\part{another test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That worked